# seek function mp4 nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

The current configuration allows us to reverse proxy + cache a certain server with video content (mp4).
The problem we have is in the seek function (go back and forth through the player on the video), this in fact takes 1-2 minutes before resuming the stream.
How can we solve this problem?

nginx.conf

```
user                www-data;
worker_processes    auto;
pid                 /run/nginx.pid;
include             /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
pcre_jit            on;

events {
    worker_connections  8096;
    use                 epoll;
    accept_mutex        on;
    multi_accept        on;
}

thread_pool mp4Cache threads=4;

http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile                on;
    sendfile_max_chunk      512k;
    tcp_nopush              on;
    tcp_nodelay             on;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    keepalive_timeout       15;
    types_hash_max_size     2048;

    open_file_cache         max=30000 inactive=5m;
    open_file_cache_valid   2m;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
    open_file_cache_errors  on;

    gzip                    on;
    gzip_comp_level         5;
    gzip_min_length         256;
    gzip_disable            "msie6";
    gzip_vary               on;
    gzip_types              application/json application/vnd.apple.mpegurl;

    include                 /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type            application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Caching & Proxy
    ##

    proxy_cache_path        /etc/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=mp4Cache:500m inactive=48h max_size=1800G use_temp_path=off;
    proxy_cache_valid       200 500m;
    proxy_set_header        Range $slice_range;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_set_header        Connection "";
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_ignore_headers    X-Accel-Expires X-Accel-Buffering Cache-Control Set-Cookie;
    proxy_cache             mp4Cache;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $http_cf_connecting_ip;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

default conf

```
server {
    server_name XXX;

    set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
    set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
    set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
    set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
    set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
    set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
    set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
    set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
    set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;
    real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;

    location /secure {
        secure_link $arg_s;
        secure_link_md5 "secret $remote_addr";
        if ( $secure_link = "" ) { return 403; }

        rewrite ^/secure/(.*)$ /$1;
    }

    location / {
        internal;
        mp4;
        slice                       20m;
        aio                         threads=mp4Cache;
        aio_write                   on;

        #mp4;
        proxy_pass                  https://XX.XX.XX.XX$uri;
        proxy_set_header            Host $host;
        proxy_buffering             on;
        proxy_pass_request_headers  on;
        proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP       $http_cf_connecting_ip;
        proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        ##
        # Caching
        ##
        #proxy_cache                mp4Cache;
        #proxy_cache_lock           on;
        proxy_cache_key             $uri;
        #proxy_cache_lock_age       24h;
        #proxy_cache_use_stale      updating;

        ##
        # Disabling Cookies
        ##
        proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
        proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
    }

    ##
    # SSL
    ##

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = XXX) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen  80;

    server_name XXX;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```